# ForEach view for collection of lists. What is the identifiable for list? Cannot convert value of type 'Text' to closure result type '_'

Tags: listview, swiftui, hashable

I have state data which is a collection of lists with key: values from json. I want to use ForEach View to show each list items in one list view but I'm getting Error. So I read that ForEach requires unique identifier, is there a hashable protocol for list like String and Int? Why am I getting this error?

```
Error:Cannot convert value of type 'Text' to closure result type '_'
struct PopUpTextView: View {
    @State private var data = [[String:Any]]()
    //let colors: [[String]] = [["red", "blue"], ["tan"],["green"], ["blue"]]

    func configureView() {
        takeRequest { (data, error) in
            print("before")
            print(data)
            self.data = data
            print("------")
            print(self.data)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(self.$data, id: \.self){ c in
                    Text(c.description)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Details")
        }.onAppear(perform:configureView)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't make it work that way - create real struct model in array.... and that error is due to `self.$data` - it should be just `self.data`, but anyway, re-read from start.

Comment: @Asperi If i do ``self.data`` I get ``Value of protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Hashable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols``. 
But why does ForEach work for ``let colors: [[String]] = [["red", "blue"], ["tan"],["green"], ["blue"]]``

Answer (score 0):

when dealing with array of dictionaries, I find it much easier to deal with the indices, such as:

```
            ForEach(self.data.indices) { index in
                Text("---> \(self.data[index].description)")
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the data variable of type String: Any?

Because if i use it like this:

```
@State private var data = [[String]]()
```

It works fine for me and no error occurs.

And of course like mention in the comments above remove the '$' in the foreach before data.

Comment: Yeah, because it's a list of keys and values.

Comment: And if you dont know the explicit type for your value you always have to check for the explicit type it could and then parse it to that type